# Identifying UserAgent strings that don't support TLSv1.1

Tags: iis, tls, useragent

I've created a tally from IIS logs of the last 18 months by User Agent string and created some Excel formulas to extract # of visits from XP/Vista machines using Internet Explorer.

Could someone confirm if the following search would accurately capture those users (XP/Vista using IE):

If (UserAgent contains "Windows+NT+6.0" OR "Windows+NT+5.1") AND (UserAgent  contains "MSIE"):  Add to total

I just want to make sure my report to management accurately reflects site traffic that won't support TLSv1.1

Comment: Do you care about clients that are not MSIE ?